# XenServer / xcp-ng networking set up virtual NAT with port forwarding

Tags: virtual-machine, port-forwarding, nat, xen, virtual-network

I have setup XenServer having a single physical NIC(PUBLIC IP) with couple VMs on it, now i need to be able to create a virtual network (LAN) with NAT allowing the VMs to communicate with each other just like in a normal LAN and to be able to go out through the public IP, and be reached from out through the public IP and port forwarding.

I used to do that in VM Ware using the virtual network editor, I really loved it, it was intuitive and straight forward, I could create several networks (NAT/BRIDGE/HOST) configure the network settings like DHCP, the range, the gateway, port forwarding and so on... Virtual box also has this(but less good than VMWare ) I was looking for that in XenServer but couldn't get it. :(

I've heard of vSwitch, but I feel its far too advanced for what I need, plus it requires another VM just for that, and I don't feel like giving it my precious resources, at least not yet.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a router so either pfSense or Windows Server Routing. Without that you could create a LAN from your Network 1 on your xenserver and even the xenserver can communicate with your vms/ However to have a public ip you will need to do natting which is only available in a routing operating syste,m